# rails-jquery-autocomplete Uncaught TypeError

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to use the rails-jquery-autocomplete gem but can't seem to get it working.

At first I thought it was the order that I was requiring it in the application.js but based on other posts on SO, I don't think this is the case. Here is that code anyway:

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require autocomplete-rails
// require turbolinks
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require bootstrap
//= require ckeditor/init
//= require social-share-button
//= require questions
// require_tree .
```

The error I am getting for it at the moment is:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function autocomplete-rails-81b10cb822d78b60a1415bace9e9714b.js?body=1:1
t.railsAutocomplete.fn.extend.initautocomplete-rails-81b10cb822d78b60a1415bace9e9714b.js?body=1:1 
t.railsAutocompleteautocomplete-rails-81b10cb822d78b60a1415bace9e9714b.js?body=1:1
t.fn.railsAutocomplete.ejquery-87424c3c19e96d4fb033c10ebe21ec40.js?body=1:4666
jQuery.event.dispatchjquery-87424c3c19e96d4fb033c10ebe21ec40.js?body=1:4334
jQuery.event.add.elemData.handlejquery-87424c3c19e96d4fb033c10ebe21ec40.js?body=1:4575
jQuery.event.triggerjquery-87424c3c19e96d4fb033c10ebe21ec40.js?body=1:4902
jQuery.event.simulatejquery-87424c3c19e96d4fb033c10ebe21ec40.js?body=1:5165
jQuery.each.handler
```

Any ideas why it's not recognising it?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first, have you run `rails generate autocomplete:install` in your project root?

Also you should include `autocomplete-rails` after `jquery-ui` which seems to be missing.

```
javascripts/application.js

//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require jquery-ui
//= require autocomplete-rails
....
```

If that does not help put this in the head of your application.haml/html:

```
layouts/application.html
....
javascript_include_tag "autocomplete-rails.js"
....
```

The [Doc](https://github.com/crowdint/rails3-jquery-autocomplete) is quite clear on what you have to do, to get up and running. Good luck

Comment: Thanks, for some reason I has somehow deleted //= require jquery-ui when I was adding the autocomplete-rails in!